# Using Payment Data Transfer after redirect to process transaction

Tags: paypal

I am using Paypal to sell license keys, which I generate on my server. I would like to be able to show the user this license key immediately after payment.

Using redirect after payment and Payment Data Transfer, I can get the transaction id after redirect. I can verify that the payment was successful, and generate the license on the spot.

I will also receive IPN messages and generate a license key if the IPN message is received as well.

I will make sure I don't process the same transaction twice. If the IPN message comes in first, then the redirect will just show the already generated license key.

I am wondering if generating license keys using the Payment Data Transfer informtion is secure, or if I should only generate their license key when I receive the IPN message.

Payment Data Transfer: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this page that I think answers my own question: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/.

Looks like it is fine to implement both.